# Passing complex hash as parameters

Tags: ruby, hash

I would like to pass these two hashes as parameters to the vertex method but Ruby does not like it.  Placing `{}` around each hash parameter also does not work.

```
vertex search_for_key: { id: '10' }, get_fields: { fullname: :full_name }
```

This works fine but I would like it on one line:

```
search = {search_for_key: { id: '10' }}
fields = {get_fields: { fullname: :full_name }}

vertex search, fields
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
vertex({search_for_key: { id: '10' }}, {get_fields: { fullname: :full_name }})
```

Comment: Thanks that works.  I was hoping to avoid all that syntactic noise.  Is there a better way to approach this in order to keep the code a lot cleaner?

Comment: @IUnknown Not while keeping everything to just one line.

Answer (score 3):

```
vertex search_for_key: { id: '10' }, get_fields: { fullname: :full_name }
```

will expand into `vertex` with a single hash as an argument. It is the same as this:

```
vertex({search_for_key: { id: '10' }, get_fields: { fullname: :full_name }})
```

Since you are expecting two arguments for `vertex`, it does not work.

Comment: +1 For explaining why what the OP has doesn’t work. But -1 for not actually giving a solution. But enough to arrive at the solution anyway, I suppose, so +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Add more curly braces and also parentheses:

```
vertex({search_for_key: { id: '10' }}, {get_fields: { fullname: :full_name }})
```